# Access Google Sheets through Google API - Does a personal project require an API to be pushed to production? Having trouble with verification

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-oauth

I have a personal project I am working on that involves me referencing one of my google spreadsheet, pulling data from it and using that data in a separate API call (3rd party API, not googles).

I have used the python quick start (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) which worked perfectly for a week, after which my token expired. I expected the below to get a new token and refresh, but that does not seem to happen.

```
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

...
...

creds.refresh(Request())
```

Instead, I get the following error, which led me on the path of turning my API on to produciton and setting up scope. I was unable to set this up though, as it asks me for domains, youtube video describing what the api will be used for, ete...

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Token has been expired or revoked.'})
```

Is this really the correct route for me to be going down to use the google API to access my personal spreadsheet?